# RISC-V Assemblers

Tags: assembly

We are going to be using a RISC-V softcore on FPGA in our work and are starting to write some basic RISC-V programs to become familiar with the ISA.

So far I have been using this (https://riscvasm.lucasteske.dev/#) RISC-V online assembler, so I can write some RISC-V assembly and then take the hex dump into memory on the FPGA.

Is there a code editor out there can do the same thing (generate hex dump from assembly) in a better environment instead of using this online assembler?

Comment: Anyone able to help me?